# Measure label size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm implementing a custom control with some labels on it and I need to measure the size of those labels to have an optimal layout. In this way I can properly show the control for each font and font size.
Could you tell me how can I do that, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to size and arrange your custom control according to the size of its sub-elements is to override [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) and [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx).

See the links for details, but in a nutshell, your control is supposed to (in MeasureOverride):

1. call `UIElement.Measure` on all children (which will include your labels), which will return the size that each of your children *would like to have*,
2. calculate your own desired size and
3. return this size to the framework (by using it as the return value of `MeasureOverride`).

Afterwards, in ArrangeOverride, you get the size allocated to your control by the framework as a parameter and you

1. determine how much of the space you want to allocate to each of your child elements and
2. call `UIElement.Arrange` on each child element.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look up ev.Graphics.MeasureString(str,font)